# How can I select which monitor to view on Google Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, logging, chrome-remote-desktop

I use Google Remote Desktop (Windows 7 client, Windows 10 server). The host has 2 monitors. When I connect to it, I see the 2 monitors: how can I select which monitor to view? Viewing 2 monitors at once makes the font size too small to read.

Comment: Hope this video can help you: [Chrome Remote Desktop with Extended Desktop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tH3li6EIwE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select which display(s) to view in the Chrome Remote Desktop's side menu:

[image]

[image]